# child swf reports 2032 Stream error in Chrome

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash

I am trying to load a child swf from another swf like this:

```
var swfLoader : Loader = new Loader();
swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,                   
   onLoaderCompleteInitialScreen);          
movieClip.addChild(swfLoader);
this.addChild(movieClip);
swfLoader.load(new URLRequest("child.swf"));

private function onLoaderCompleteInitialScreen(e : Event) : void {
        var dobj : DisplayObject = DisplayObject(e.currentTarget.content);
        dobj.addEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE,
            initalScreenSWFAppComplete);
}
```

I deploy this code on a Tomcat server running on my machine.

If I load the parent swf from local browser : myMachineIp/parent.swf the parent swf works great, but the child swf loads corectly only in IE and Firefox. It doesn't work in Chrome. It reports #2032 error.

If I try to load the parent swf from a browser running on another computer, the child swf will report 2032 error on all browsers.

I can see that the Loader's event complete comes, which means the swf is reachable but the initalScreenSWFAppComplete is not executed anymore.

I really don't know what could be the problem. Since the Loader completes, I assume that there is no crossdomain problem, the swf is reachable, right? What else could trigger this?

Thanks in advance,
Miha

Comment: I've been seeing a lot of Chrome-related issues here lately. I think I read somewhere they created their own runtime. Which seems to be having some bugs...

Comment: Agree with @RIAstar .. disable PepperFlash and it should work in chrome also locally.  The fact that you said "running on another computer, the child swf will report 2032 error on all browsers." leads me to believe you also have a crossdomain.xml issue. Locally in flash debugger you wouldn't see this... remotely you would.

Comment: What puzzles me is that the Loader's complete event is dispatched....wouldn't that mean the child swf is reachable? I thought that based on this I can exclude crossdomain issues, or?